# set column to 'not null' in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in a table in a sql server database that I want to set to 'not null'. However, when I execute the query

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN mycolumn INT NOT NULL
```

I get  an

```
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN mycolumn failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

How can I find out what kind of object that is and how do I drop it? The database is very simple and is not supposed to make use of foreign keys, triggers etc.

Comment: try restarting sql server service.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could search the `sys` tables to find out what is dependent on the column.  This has its limitations, naturally, but by-and-large should give you some indication of what is dependent on your column:

```
SELECT
     OBJECT_NAME(D.Object_ID) AS [Dependent]
    ,D.Object_ID
FROM sys.sql_dependencies D
INNER JOIN sys.Columns C
    ON C.object_id = D.referenced_major_id
    AND C.column_id = D.referenced_minor_id
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(C.object_id) = 'MyTable'
AND C.name = 'MyColumn'
;
```

Once you have the name and `object_id` of the dependent (it might be a function, a stored procedure, or any number of things) you can go from there.

Answer (score 1):

You  might have  to drop constraints on the column first,before altering this table.This may be  a constraint,index or any thing..below is a small demo showing the same

```
create table #test
(
id int,
id1 int
)

create index nci_t on #test(id1)
include(id)

alter table #test
alter column id1 varchar(10)
```

this is the error i got

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   The index 'nci_t' is dependent on column 'id1'.
>   Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 2
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN id1 failed because one or more objects access this column.

also please paste entire error message ,don't strip it